# MySQL server attempting connection to wrong location

Tags: mysql, localhost

I moved the MySQL database to an external hard drive several months back and has been working fine. However it has recently stopped searching for the database connection in this new location and is searching my c drive again. 
As a result I'm getting the following error:

Checking server status...
Trying to connect to MySQL...
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
Assuming server is not running

How do I get the MySQL server to search the correct location?

If there is any additional information needed, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check to see if the mysql service is running?

Comment: That is the error that comes up when I try to start the server in the 'startup/shutdown MySQL Server' tab. Is that what you mean?